# Zoom with Helixtoolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, leap-motion, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm trying to use a Leap Motion to control an 3D object with Helix Toolkit, and I am almost succeeding, but I'm wondering how to do "zoom" in the code-behind.

N.B. I'm using Caliburn (MVVM pattern).

I want to zoom in when I do a clockwise CircleAction, and zoom out otherwise:

```
public void CircleAction(bool isClockWise)
{
    if (!detectionActive)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (isClockWise)
    {
        // To do
    }
    else
    {
        //To do
    }
}
```

And here is my HelixToolkit zone:

```
        <HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera 
                Position="{Binding CameraPosition,Mode=TwoWay}"
                LookDirection="{Binding CameraDirection,Mode=TwoWay}"
                UpDirection="{Binding Camera.UpDirection}"
                FieldOfView="{Binding Camera.FieldOfView}"
             />
        </HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D.Camera>

    </HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D>
```

Comment: Zooming is done with the CameraController of the HelixViewport3D. Unlukily there is no direct way to bind to it. I could think of using a custom Decorator which enables to bind to an zoom command or something similar

Answer (score 0):

From the [SurfaceDemo](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/tree/08bf8543cfdf62a59ccfd9a4c5f8e7034f05ad59/Source/Examples/WPF/SurfaceDemo) example in the [helix-toolkit source](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit) and the [documentation for the `CameraController` class](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/HelixToolkit/HelixToolkit.Wpf/CameraController), I can suggest the following.

XAML:

```
<HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D x:Name="myViewPort3D">
<!-- ... -->
</HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D>
```

Code-behind:

```
public void CircleAction(bool isClockWise)
{
    if (!detectionActive)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (isClockWise)
    {
        myViewPort3D.CameraController.zoom(delta);
    }
    else
    {
        myViewPort3D.CameraController.zoom(-delta);
    }
}
```